# Why is UnrealHeaderTool failing when building RPCs

Tags: c++, rpc, unreal-engine4

In my header file for a pawn I'm attempting to declare an RPC. The following compiles properly:

`UFUNCTION( ) void ClientSetPosition(FTransform position);`

Yet this does not compile:

`UFUNCTION( Client ) void ClientSetPosition(FTransform position);`

I Get the following error:

`UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'MultiEditor' (platform: Win64, module info: C:\Users\myself\Documents\Unreal Projects\Multi\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MultiEditor\Development\MultiEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code: OtherCompilationError (5)).`

`The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.21\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" MultiEditor Win64 Development "C:\Users\myself\Documents\Unreal Projects\Multi\Multi.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.`

Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resolved the issue:
UFUNCTION( Client, Reliable)

They must have updated unreal to require this variable.

Comment: Specifying the Reliable/Unreliable has always been required.

Comment: @DevilsD that's not true, rpcs used to be unreliable by default. In fact this was true recently enough that the docs haven't been updated. https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/InteractiveExperiences/Networking/Actors/RPCs/index.html

Comment: If your game/simulation allows any sort of drop in feature. I'd consider using a rep notify instead, since a client that connects after this rpc has fired will never receive the info it sends (granted this isn't important 100% of the time - but just thought it was worth pointing out).

Comment: Thanks for the tip George. I'll keep this in mind for dynamic replicated object addition if I add it. This particular example is to replicate the position of client controlled objects to other clients. Thus it is happening constantly.